# How to change the duration of SCLAlertView according to response from server in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to implement the SCLAlertView for server response. I am using UIActivityIndicatorView for that and my code is like this

```
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(510,280)];

    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
```

and after response from server

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

But now I want to use the AlertView of SCLAlertView and its code is like this

```
SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];

    alert.showAnimationType = SCLAlertViewHideAnimationSlideOutToCenter;
    alert.hideAnimationType = SCLAlertViewHideAnimationSlideOutFromCenter;

    alert.backgroundType = SCLAlertViewBackgroundBlur;

    [alert showWaiting:self title:@"Waiting..."
              subTitle:@"You've just displayed this awesome Pop Up View with transparent background"
      closeButtonTitle:nil duration:5.0f];
```

And it output is like this

[image]

I need to display this AlertView till I get the data from server. Means I need to stop it in "DidFinishLoading Method". Just like UIActivityIndicatorView. Is it is possible anyone done this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can not hide or dismiss the SCLAlertView . Either you can give the duration of alert or you can set "done" button.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way either you add a done button or you can add this method after get the data from server.

```
alert.isVisible = NO;
```

Then add this for remove from view.But it is interactive for user.

```
alert.shouldDismissOnTapOutside = YES;
```